# Horror short story with an upbeat ending

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

This short story might have been about teenagers or adults, and was written in the 1980's or 1990's. It could have been in a Charles de Lint anthology, as the genre was fantasy horror. I don't think it involved vampires, but resurrection was a central theme. The ending was not horrific, actually positive though a little ambiguous. The last sentences, *paraphrased* as best as I can remember, are the protagonist thinking, third person point of view:

> He held her closely. She was cold as the grave but steadily warming...

What is the title and author of this story?

Comment: Are you certain it was about teenagers? I remember a similar story involving an adult where he found his wife had somehow survived the zombie epidemic, and ended with a similar line, indicating that she'd been dead the whole time.

Comment: @SeanDuggan No, I'm not certain it was about teenagers actually. Tell me more, or better yet, write it as an answer please!

Comment: Problem is, I only have vague memories of that one, but I will see if I can find it.